# Booting up a Mac from the USB flash drive

Tags: mac, usb, boot, usb-flash-drive

Is it possible to boot from a USB flash drive on a Mac?

Current setup is an iMac (early 2008) running Snow Leopard. What do I need to do to have the Mac boot from the USB stick?

Comment: check the BIOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the device in Startup Disk preferences, **or** hold the option key when booting to access the Startup Manager and select your volume as the boot device.

More info and necessary requirements for the device can be found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1948) (apparently the method is the same [for powerpc based Macs](http://www.tuaw.com/2006/10/25/boot-your-powerpc-mac-from-an-external-usb-drive/)).

Answer (score 0):

All Intel based Macintosh computers can boot from USB, and Firewire devices.  PowerPC based systems are not generally able to be booted from USB, but can be booted from Firewire devices.